# Calculating the electric potential in the Lorenz gauge

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, gauge

It has been a while since I have done any electromagnetism, and at one point I knew how to do this but for the life of me can't figure this out. The problem is as follows, if we have a time dependent charge at the origin given by:

$$q(t)=q_0\sin(\omega t)$$

How can we find the electric potential $\Phi$ in the Lorenz gauge? $\Phi$ must satisfy the following equation in the Lorenz gauge:

$$-\nabla^2\Phi +\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial t^2}=\frac{\rho(\mathbf{x},t)}{\epsilon}$$

I'm pretty sure that we have:

$$\rho(\mathbf{x},t)=q_0\sin(\omega t)\delta^3(\mathbf{x})$$
but other than that I have no idea where to go from here. I can readily write the potential in the coulomb gauge, is there away I can make gauge transformation without knowing/finding $\mathbf{A}$?

Comment: Without a current there is no charge conservation and without charge conservation Maxwell's equations do not apply. Some clarification is needed.

Comment: The only context I was given was that there is a charge at the origin with time dependence.  Can current not be given by $\frac{dq}{dt}$

Comment: You are correct. The current is not needed to find $\Phi$.

Comment: @my2cts ok so then what context is needed?

Comment: In Lorenz Gauge the solution to the wave equation of the electrical potential is given by $\phi(\mathbf{x},t) = \frac{1}{4\pi} \int d^3y \frac{\rho(\mathbf{y},t-|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|/c)}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|}$. The delta-distribution in the charge density makes this integral trivial. The solution also makes sense intuitively.

Comment: Do you know where I can see I derivation of this greens function?

Comment: The missing context is whether the current is conserved. If it is not the Maxwell equations do not apply

Comment: @ChristopherQuinnLaFondJr. LMGTFY: http://www.physics.sfsu.edu/~lea/courses/oldgrad/grad/wavemks.pdf

Comment: Griffiths 10.3.2.